# Speed up foreach for nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

Ok I have a nested array that returns objects which are then traversed to retrirve the id's which are then used to retrieve another array which is traversed and the values returned are echoed out the problem is this seems to take ages in the browserto work across how do i go abut speeding this up? 
the code is as follows: 
this is the first function:

```
 /**
 * Get a page of Campaigns
 * @param string $page - url to page of campaigns, default is first page
 * @return array - array of Campaign objects and a link to the next page if one exists
 */
public function getCampaigns($page=null){
    $page = ($page) ? $this->CTCTRequest->baseUri.$page : $this->uri;
    $campaignsCollection = array('campaigns' => array(), 'nextLink' => '');
    $response = $this->CTCTRequest->makeRequest($page, 'GET');
    $parsedResponse = simplexml_load_string($response['xml']);
    foreach ($parsedResponse->entry as $entry){
        $campaignsCollection['campaigns'][] = new Campaign(Campaign::createOverviewStruct($entry));
    }
    $campaignsCollection['nextLink'] = Utility::findNextLink($parsedResponse);
    return $campaignsCollection;
}
```

this is the second function:

```
/**
 * Get detailed Campaign object
 * @param string $url - url of a Campiagn
 * @return Campaign
 */
public function getCampaignDetails($url){
    $response = $this->CTCTRequest->makeRequest($url, 'GET');
    $parsedReturn = simplexml_load_string($response['xml']);
    return new Campaign(Campaign::createStruct($parsedReturn));
}
```

this is the code that traverses both of these and returns my values:

```
<?php
/*
*
*
*grab the  Campaign array
*
*
*/
$getallCampaigns = $ConstantContact->getCampaigns(false);
?>
<table class="CTCTtable">
<tr>
    <th>Campaign Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Sent#</th>
    <th>Opens</th>
    <th>Clicks</th>
    <th>Bounces</th>
    <th>Forwards</th>
    <th>OptOuts</th>
    <th>SpamReports</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($getallCampaigns as $tableName => $tableData) { // Loop outer array
  foreach ($tableData as $row) { // Loop table rows
      $originalDate = $row->campaignDate;
      $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
        //get campaign details
      $getallCampaignevents = $ConstantContact->getCampaignDetails($row);
     //$getallCampaignsends =  $ConstantContact->getCampaignSends($row);
        //    
        //echo  $getallCampaignevents->name;
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td><a title="'.$getallCampaignevents->name.'"href="'.$getallCampaignevents->id.'">'.$getallCampaignevents->name.'</a></td>';
      echo '<td>'.$newDate.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$getallCampaignevents->status.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$getallCampaignevents->campaignSent.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$getallCampaignevents->campaignOpens.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$getallCampaignevents->campaignClicks.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$getallCampaignevents->campaignBounces.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$getallCampaignevents->campaignForwards.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$getallCampaignevents->campaignOptOuts.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$getallCampaignevents->campaignSpamReports.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    // var_dump($getallCampaignevents);
  }
}
?>
</table>
```

here is an example of the first returned array:

```
    array(2) {
  ["campaigns"]=>
  array(50) {
    [0]=>
    object(Campaign)#68 (48) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(26) "*****************************"
      ["id"]=>
      string(74) "***********************************************"
      ["link"]=>
      string(44) "************************"
      ["status"]=>
      string(4) "Sent"
      ["campaignDate"]=>
      string(24) "2013-12-05T21:28:07.330Z"
      ["urls"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Campaign)#68 (48) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(26) "*****************************"
      ["id"]=>
      string(74) "***********************************************"
      ["link"]=>
      string(44) "************************"
      ["status"]=>
      string(4) "Sent"
      ["campaignDate"]=>
      string(24) "2013-12-05T21:28:07.330Z"
      ["urls"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
}
```

This is the second returend array:

```
    object(Campaign)#64 (48) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(26) "*************"
  ["id"]=>
  string(74) "***************"
  ["link"]=>
  string(44) "************************"
  ["status"]=>
  string(4) "Sent"
  ["campaignDate"]=>
  string(24) "2013-12-05T21:28:07.330Z"
  ["lastEditDate"]=>
  string(24) "2013-12-02T14:52:13.629Z"
  ["lastRunDate"]=>
  string(24) "2013-12-05T21:28:07.327Z"
  ["campaignSent"]=>
  string(2) "13"
  ["campaignOpens"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["campaignClicks"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["campaignBounces"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["campaignForwards"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["campaignOptOuts"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["campaignSpamReports"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["subject"]=>
  string(33) "Offers, and your feedback please!"
  ["fromName"]=>
  string(18) "***************"
  ["campaignType"]=>
  string(5) "STOCK"
  ["hiveStatus"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["archiveUrl"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
object(Campaign)#56 (56) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(26) "*************"
  ["id"]=>
  string(74) "***************"
  ["link"]=>
  string(44) "************************"
  ["status"]=>
  string(4) "Sent"
  ["campaignDate"]=>
  string(24) "2013-12-05T21:28:07.330Z"
  ["lastEditDate"]=>
  string(24) "2013-12-02T14:52:13.629Z"
  ["lastRunDate"]=>
  string(24) "2013-12-05T21:28:07.327Z"
  ["campaignSent"]=>
  string(2) "13"
  ["campaignOpens"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["campaignClicks"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["campaignBounces"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["campaignForwards"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["campaignOptOuts"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["campaignSpamReports"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["subject"]=>
  string(33) ""
  ["fromName"]=>
  string(18) "***************"
  ["campaignType"]=>
  string(5) "STOCK"
  ["hiveStatus"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["archiveUrl"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I'm using Constant Contact's OAuth's API with this php wrapper to return these arrays: 
[it can be found here](https://github.com/shannon7wallace/OAuth-2-PHP-Example)

Comment: I think bottleneck in `Campaign` class costructor, or in `createOverviewStruct` method of this class. how big `$parsedResponse` ?

Comment: $parsed response is : 394 KB but it's topping 20secs to load...

Comment: may be if you find a way to not create the Campaign object on each step it could speedup this

Comment: suggestion with an example I'll gladly except the answer!

Comment: I can't get you example because have no idea what Campaign class is